# how to get a value from db when searched date falls in between from_date and to_date mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table which has costs for rooms based on `from_date` and `to_date`:

Format of db:

```
planid | roomtype_id | capacity_id | hotel_id |date_from | date_to | cost
```

and I want to get the cost of room based on arrival date which is stored in a input field when the `arrival_date` falls in between `date_from` and `date_to`

My code:

```
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM room_price WHERE roomtype_id = '$roomtype_id' AND capacity_id = '$capacity_id' AND hotel_id = '$hotel_id' AND date_from '$date' BETWEEN date_from AND date_to");
```

The query doesn't gives any output.

Comment: Did you even google about this?

Comment: You **really** should not be writing code that relies on `mysql_` functions anymore. The MySQL extension has been deprecated for years (ever notice these red warning boxes in the documentation?) and is about to be dropped in the upcoming PHP7 release, which can be released any time now. Also see [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). On an up-to-date server, this code has a life span of about a month, after which **it will stop working**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is that , your\ are using two dates in mysql table colum, so you have to check as i have given code below:

```
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM room_price WHERE roomtype_id = '$roomtype_id' AND capacity_id = '$capacity_id' AND hotel_id = '$hotel_id' AND date_from >='$date' And date_to<=$date");
```

Comment: $result1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM room_price WHERE roomtype_id = '$roomtype_id' AND capacity_id = '$capacity_id' AND hotel_id = '$hotel_id' AND date_from <= '$date' AND date_to >= '$date'");

Comment: hmmm i forget to add quote to last date variable$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM room_price WHERE roomtype_id = '$roomtype_id' AND capacity_id = '$capacity_id' AND hotel_id = '$hotel_id' AND date_from >='$date' And date_to<='$date'");

Comment: give me your mysql table create query

Answer (score 0):

try this query:

```
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM room_price WHERE roomtype_id = '$roomtype_id' AND capacity_id = '$capacity_id' AND hotel_id = '$hotel_id' AND BETWEEN 'your_from_Date' AND 'your_to_date'");
```

Comment: i have only one date to check the cost which falls under date_from and date_to